# Regulations about the new requirement to provide social media accounts for US visas

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

Starting from June 1st of 2019, all applicants to US visas are [required](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/02/us/us-visa-application-social-media.html) to provide information about social media accounts they have used in the past five years.

I wasn't able to find any document that regulates the following scenarios.

- What if someone used say Facebook in the last five years but deleted their account a few months ago? Shall they restore the account and provide a link to it? Or shall they provide a link to the deleted account? I assume not mentioning that account will be considered a lie because they have used that account in the past five years. On the other hand, if I deleted an account, I do not use it "to collaborate, share information, and interact with others" (see the text in bold below), so is there no need to list it? A subquestion: what if one, after deleting their account, periodically restores it (say once a month) to contact someone? Should they keep the account alive for the time when the application is considered? Or should one guided by the rule that all information that is provided in the application must be topical at that time, and if at the time of application the account was inactive, then one should not list it, regardless of whether or not the account will be restored after the application has been submitted?
- If one's account (again say on Facebook) has very strict privacy settings (so that even friends cannot see anything), should these privacy settings be modified so that the immigration inspector can see everything that the account owner can see (except private messages and things like that)?
- <s>What if someone has 2 or more Facebook accounts? I don't know whether there is an option to submit two or more accounts for one social network, but what if not? Again, not listing all accounts will be considered a lie, as far as I understand.</s> According to a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL06K.png) of the part of the new application form about social media, there is an option to add more than one account. Moreover, I believe there is no need to list the accounts that one doesn't use (see below).
- <s>What if one have used some social network in the last five years, but doesn't remember the username/email/etc. because e.g. they signed up there 4 years ago using a temporary/fake email?</s> Here are instructions from the screenshot I mentioned above: *Enter information associated with your online presence, including the types of online providers/platforms, applications and websites **that you use to collaborate, share information, and interact with others**.* Thus I believe there is no need to provide the type of account described in this bullet.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum you need to do to satisfy their request is:

- List the name(s) of social media accounts you have used in the last five years.

If those accounts(s) have since been deleted, then you are under no obligation to attempt to "un-delete" them (which may not even be possible, depending on the platform). You do not have to change any privacy settings, either. They just asked for names.

If you happened to use a social media account within the last 5 years and you have either forgotten you did so, or forget the username, then clearly you can't list the username and you would have to suffer the consequences if their systems remember something that you have forgotten.

Comment: If I'm only required to list the accounts that I "use to collaborate, share information, and interact with others" and if I do not use those "forgotten" accounts for the mentioned purposes (in fact, I do not use them at all), I'm not breaking any rules if I'm not listing them, am I? Why would I have to suffer the consequences then?

Comment: And it still remains unclear whether un-deleting accounts (that were deleted at the time of submission) after application submission is acceptable or not.

Comment: How is it possible to even open a social media account without "sharing information" and "interacting with others?" Consider too that if you decline to name a platform because you assert that you never "shared info" or "interacted with others" there, and the visa authorities find that account that you opened but "didn't use," they'll happily disbelieve you and deny your application.

Comment: @David My understanding is that "sharing information" includes making your own posts, reposting other's posts, or commenting. It's perfectly possible to have a social media account without doing any of these. If, additionally, an accout was created to check a particular social network out (or if one doesn't have any friends using this social network), then not interacting with others is a natural thing to do. For your last sentence, this certainly can be the case, but the application has a precise definition of what accounts one should provide, and I don't see any violations from my side.

Comment: Sure, that's one interpretation. Another is that signing up, which discloses some information about you to the wider world, is in itself _sharing information_. I think that wrestling with visa-issuing authorities rarely ends well for the applicant, but I confess to being risk-averse. YMMV.